# Como adicionar fontes aditivas além das oferecidas pelo Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Como posso adicionar fontes tipográficas além das oferecidas pelo Visual Studio?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu desconfio que não sejam as fontes do Windows pois o Visual Studio não lista algumas fontes específicas.

Comment: Acredito que ele lista as Fontes instaladas no Windows. Instale a fonte e reinicie o Visual Studio para listá-las.

Comment: @Tony responde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Visual Studio lista as Fontes *True Type* instaladas no Windows. Instale a fonte e reinicie o Visual Studio para listá-las.

Existe uma fonte chamada [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), que faz ligaduras em símbolos comumente utilizados na programação:

[image: FiraCode]

Outro exemplo, a fonte Bebas:
[image: Font]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para obter mais fontes, pode dar uma olhada em [Free TTF Fonts](https://www.bing.com/search?q=free%20TTF%20fonts):

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/273643/194717

Comment: Eu desconfiava que não seria uma verdade por conta que, ele não lista algumas fontes específicas. Bebas e etc. Deve ter algum padrão.

Comment: Ainda assim, obrigado!

Comment: Ele lista as Fontes True Type

Comment: A `Bebas` que você tem aí é esta? https://www.dafont.com/bebas.font
Testei aqui e ela apareceu.

Comment: Era de outro tipo, Tony. Acredito que seja OTF. Mas, havia dito Bebas somente como exemplo mesmo. A fonte que eu desejava que aparecesse na lista fui atrás de uma versão TTF e apareceu normalmente.